# Unable to add footerview to PullToRefreshListView

Tags: android

I am using:

**https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh**

```
PullToRefreshListView listView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, listView, false);
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

**I get the Error:**

> The method addFooterView(View) is undefined for the type
>   PullToRefreshListView

How to solve it?

Thank You

Comment: post the full logcat :)

Comment: Its a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

To add footer view, you have to get the pure ListView first then you can use it to add Footer View. You have to call **getRefreshableView()** to get pure ListView. Here is the sample code:

```
PullToRefreshListView listView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, listView, false);

//get ListView object first, and then add footer view
listView.getRefreshableView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the normal ListView first, then use the normal ListView's addFooterView function.

```
ListView mList = listView.getRefreshableView();
mList.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer.